When external monitor connected, I need to switch between 2 keyboards 4 times
I have Lenovo Thinkpad T14 and I connect it through HDMI to ACER CB270HU. My Lenovo runs on Windows 11. I only have two keyboards: Russian and German (Switzerland) for typing in two languages and I switch between them with Shift+Alt. As soon as I connect my monitor to laptop, I need to press Shift+Alt three times to switch a correct language. For example,
now I am typing in German, do Shift+Alt to switch to Russian and it does switch. Then I do Shift Alt again and language display in tray stays RU, but it actually has English keyboard. Then I do Shift Alt again, the RU icon stays the same, but it has French keyboard.
Seems like when an external monitor is connected, the keyboard just goes crazy and I can't explain it. Maybe someone has a hint for me?
Thanks

Which operating system are you using?

The keyboard layout switches for whichever app you have active. I suspect that connecting an external monitor, changes the desktop layout, which gives focus to another application, which changes the keyboard layout.

@Randomhero the keyboard shortcut keys is windows, and not much changed with this since windows 95 I think, so most likely windows 10 or 11, but that's a guess. Probably won't change the answer anyway though.

Windows 11. So there's no solution to this?

@LPChip I was only asking to make sure that it wasn't a Linux issue which would potentially have a different solution

You could use keyboard layout in combination with keyboard language. You then have ALT+SHIFT, but also CTRL+SHIFT, so cycling is faster.

I am so bad at it and sorry, I didn't understand how to use layout and keyboard language at the same time?

Please add the OS and other info you've been requested to add to the question itself. This will help make your question more clear and will increase the odds someone who has the right information will find it and get you a good answer.

Thanks, I added this info to the question itself.
